# UIPickerView - gradient broken in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uipickerview

Before iOS 8, able to set a gradient background to a UIPickerView so the spinner would show on top and behind it, a gradient background as shown here:

[image]

Here is the code for the above prior to iOS 8:

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = pickerView.bounds;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   (id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor],
                   (id)[[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor],
                   (id)[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor],
                   (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor],
                   (id)[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor],
                   (id)[[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor],
                   (id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor],
                   nil];

[pickerView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

Using the above code in iOS 8, here is what displays:

[image: <PastedGraphic-2.tiff>]

Both pickers still function, but as you can see, the UI is not acceptable.

Suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Vidhi - you mentioned more specific tags, what more specific does it need? The problem is, the code I posted worked for iOS 6 & 7, but not in iOS 8. I need to know how to make the gradient background appear 'behind' the picker selector level. As of iOS 8, the logic I used (addSubLayer :atIndex) is putting it on TOP of everything. Suggestions? Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found a work-around, but still open to other, better options. My solution is:

1. Make UIPickerView backgroundColor transparent
2. Place a UILabel behind the UIPickerView
3. Create my gradient as above and add it to the UILabel as a subLayer :atIndex 0

Here is the code sample:

```
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = colorPickerBackgroundLabel.bounds;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   (id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor],
                   (id)[[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor],
                   (id)[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor],
                   (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor],
                   (id)[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor],
                   (id)[[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor],
                   (id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor],
                   nil];
[colorPickerBackgroundLabel.layer addSublayer:gradient];
```

Here is the finished screen area capture:

[image: Finished UIPicker w/ gradient background]